# Restangular, AngularJS and Kendo UI Grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, restangular

My problem is I'm using the kendo-grid as follows

in index.html

```
<table kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions" k-ng-delay="gridOptions" id="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="type">Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="asset in assets">
      <td>{{asset.type}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and using a factory for restangular

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('assetFactory', function (Restangular) {
return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) { 
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('my/service/url');
  });
});
```

then in assetCtrl

```
assetFactory.all('cases').getList().then(function(assets) {
  $scope.assets =   assets;
});
.......
.......
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        sortable: true,
        selectable: true,
        scrollable: true,
        groupable: true,
        height:790,
        pageable: {
            pageSize: 25,
            input: true
        }
    };
}, 500);
```

now it is working but I'm not able to add more attributes for columns or updating because everything is generated in the index.html so I feel like I have no control on it.

So I want to make it something like this

in index.html just

```
<kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions" k-ng-delay="gridOptions">
</kendo-grid>
```

and keeping the factory as it is (using Restangular)

then in assetCtrl

```
var myData = new kendo.data.dataSource{
    data: **// assign the assets here**
}
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        dataSource: myData,
        columns: [ 
           **//fields with attributes like filtering for each col**
         ]
        sortable: true,
        selectable: true,
        scrollable: true,
        groupable: true,
        height:790,
        pageable: {
            pageSize: 25,
            input: true
        }
    };
}, 500);
```

Also can anyone tell me how should my service return look like ?? json array or .... ?

Any help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a few months old, but I had to figure out how to make Restangular and Kendo UI Grid play nice today. I eventually came across the kendo.data.DataSource api as a reference: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read

Note: There's some solutions out there recommending using Datasource.push or DataSource.add and essentially transferring your json array via a for-loop.  That's a bad idea since .add and .push both trigger an update.

Anyway, the solution using DataSource.transport.read:

Angular HTML Template:

```
    <kendo-grid k-options="mainGridOptions"></kendo-grid>
```

Pertinent Controller Code:

```
// Set the columns of the grid. 'title' is the Label, 'field' is the corresponding json field name. 
var kGridColumns = [
        {title: "Asset Type", field: "asset"},
        {title: "Asset Case Name", field: "name"},
        {title: "Asset Case ID", field: "id"},

    ]; 

// Create a new Kendo DataSource and set the transport.read to a function.
var kDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        pageSize: 10,
        transport:{
            read:function(e){

                 var assetListPromise= assetFactory.all('cases').getList();

                assetListPromise.then(function(resp){
                    // Use .plain() to strip out all the excess Restangular features from the response
                    var plain = resp.plain();
                    // Pass your data back to the datasource/grid
                    e.success(plain);
                });
                assetListPromise.catch(function(resp){
                    var msg = "Issue loading asset cases:"+JSON.stringify(resp);
                    e.error(msg)
                });
            }
        }
    });

// Set the scope object with our columns and datasource config
$scope.mainGridOptions = {
        dataSource: kDataSource,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: kGridColumns
    };
```